# How to refactor filters usage

Tags: javascript, php, html

There are some filters on my website for easier going through a table with some data. The table following like this:

`id | name | price`

Aims are

1. sorting select filter (id, name, price)
2. order select (asc, desc)
3. max number on one page select (10, 50, 100, 200)
4. pagination (page variable)

Bu the problems are:

1) A lot of get variables
2) Default link has to have ?sort=id&order=desc parameter
3) Mess in html/php code - replacing, removing, setting, comparing get variables
4) Performance

Is there a way to do it better?

Comment: The question is to broad and an answer would be based on personal opinion. See [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The question should be closed because it doesn't a started trouble

Comment: just do it, you have a problem list :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with JavaScript.
For example with https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: you can't `sort&paginate` on client-side without fetching of all data you have